# optimize variables in Anylogic

Tags: anylogic

I was trying to do some optimization with Anylogic. My question is that what if I want to optimize a variable and not a parameter? For example I want to minimize the cost function. I want to find the optimal values of three variable,

```
cost = -6 A -8 B -9 C
```

A,B,C represents the shipping costs for different warehouses .
I cannot define cost as a parameter, so how can I optimize it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You don't optimize for parameters in AnyLogic but you define an objective function for which to optimize. In the optimization experiment properties where you define it, you can access any variable or any other object from your model (using `root.`).

Hence it is no problem to optimize across several variables. What the optimization does is vary some parameters that you specify in its properties.

I suggest you check out some simple optimization example models to see how it is supposed to work. Hope this helps